# Why is Gravityforms Nested Forms showing view entry links on mini cart for non admin?

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

As the title describes it, Gravityforms Nested Forms is showing view entry links on mini cart. (I don't think it should for non-admins)

Is there any way to hide it?

Screenshot below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYkR3.jpg

Comment: Have you submitted a support ticket? We'll be happy to see what we can do. https://gravitywiz.com/support/

Comment: I figured it was some sort of bug since it was showing for non logged in users as well. The client didn't share his perks login so that might take awhile.